# Is there a way to share a link with only a spefic mail recipient?

Tags: javascript, python, email, security

Not sure if this question should come to SO, but here it goes.

I have the following scenario:

A Flask app with typical users that can login using username / password. Users can share some resources among them, but now we want to let them share those with anyone, not users of the app basically.

Because the resources content is important, only the person that received the email should be able to access the resource. Not everyone with the link, in other words.

What I've thought so far:

- Create a one-time link -> This could work, but I'd prefer if the link is permanent
- Add some Javascript in the HTML email message sent and add a parameter to the request sent so I can make sure the email address that opened the link was the correct one. This assuming that I can do that with Javascript...which is not clear to me. This will make the link permanent though.

Any toughts? Thanks

Comment: Wait, is that sending an email to _one_ person and ensuring that only that person can access some resource (which is presumably not enclosed in the email) or is that sending an email to a group of people but trying to only reveal some information to one of them?

Comment: Hello @vlaz this means sending an email to one person, the resource in included as a link, not directly

Comment: So, would a service like [this](https://onetimesecret.com/) or [this](https://1ty.me/) suffice or do you want to make similar functionality yourself? Or if you want to use this, do you want to make sure _only_ the recipient will be able to get to the link (say, ensuring that the email does not get intercepted and somebody goes to the link before the recipient)?

Comment: Javascript is ignored in HTML email.

Comment: @vlaz Those services are both one-time links. He said he's looking for something that's permanent. I don't think it's possible. When someone goes to the link, there's no way for the server to know if the link came from the original email or a copy.

Comment: Google couldn't solve this in Google Docs. They give you two choices: documents that are accessible by anyone with the URL, and documents that are only accessible by specified GD users and groups.

Comment: @Barmar well, you could have some crypto there where the recipient of the email will have some secret that is needed to access the resource. You could throw in asymmetric encryption if the intention is to prevent Eve from using the information in the email to reach the resource. Or perhaps that's simply an overkill.

Comment: @vlaz Whatever you use, they can share it with whoever they forward the link to. If it's asymmetric encryption, that requires the recipient to have uploaded something to the server so it can recognize their certificate, but the basic premise is that these links should be usable by random recipients, not people with accounts.

Comment: If you want to restrict content to a specific person, _make that person log in to your application_.  There's no other secure way to do it.

Comment: @vlaz my idea is that only real recipient access the video, if possible, but not just a one-time only

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure JS is ignored? I'm puzzled to hear that, as there are many services that actuallly track all user interaction with those mails (MailChimp for instance)...how do they do it without JS?

Comment: @JohnGordon I need to let the user view the content at least once without loggin in...

Comment: @AlejandroVK then option 1. add a token in the url and only people with valid tokens will be able to see the resource. On the other hand _anybody_ with a valid URL will be able to see the resource and URLs are not secret. 2. Require a login and track which user is granted access to what.

Comment: Actually, if you need a preview, then you can combine 1. and 2. and generate a link that only works once or for a limited time - e.g. 24 hours but then gets deactivated and it requires a login.

Comment: Do  you know in advance anything about the link recipients?  Or are they chosen arbitrarily by your users?

Comment: @JohnGordon nope, randomly selected

Comment: @AlejandroVK They do it with web bugs. These are typically 1-pixel images, where the source URL runs a script that performs the tracking.

Comment: @Barmar so it can be done?

Comment: No, web bugs don't use Javascript, they use `<img>`. Actually, even if mail readers did run Javascript, how would that help? If someone forwards the mail, that will include the JS.

Comment: Worth noting that the tracking pixels (a.k.a. web bugs) don't work unless the image is loaded and not all email clients do that automatically.

Comment: @Barmar good point...

Comment: @vlaz That's correct. We use SendGrid, and I've confirmed that they don't track emails being opened by recipients who disable remote images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time someone accesses the URL, you could send them a random cookie, and save that cookie with the document. On future accesses, check if the cookie matches the saved cookie. If they share the URL with someone, that person won't have the cookie.

Caveats:

1. If they share the URL with someone else, and the other person goes to the URL first, **they** will be the one who can access it, not the original recipient.
2. If the recipient clears cookies, they'll lose access to the document. You'll need a recovery procedure. This could send a new URL to the original email address.

Comment: sounds like a good plan and both caveats will be weird, I don't expect users to send the link to anyone to be honest, but is just to be sure